# A proof in harmonic analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am checking the proof of the following proposition:

Suppose $K\in C^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n/ \{0\}\right)$ is a homogeneous of degree $1-n$. Then $p.v.\nabla K(x)$ is well defined tempered distribution and satisfies

$$\nabla K=c\delta_0+p.v.\nabla K$$ where the latter $\nabla K$ is pointwise and $\displaystyle c=\int_{S^{n-1}}k(x)\,\frac{x}{\left\lvert x\right\rvert}\,d\sigma(x)$.

In the proof we can write the distribution as

$$
\nabla K=\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0 \\ R\to\infty}} \left(\int_{\varepsilon\leq \left\lvert x\right\rvert\leq R}\nabla K(x)\phi(x)\,dx-\int_{\partial A(\varepsilon,R)}K(x)\phi(x)\vec{\nu}(x)\,d\sigma(x)\right)
$$

then we let $\varepsilon\to 0,\,R\to\infty$, we get the result. However I am wondering if we write 
$\displaystyle\int_{\partial A\left(\varepsilon,R\right)}K(x)\phi(x)\vec{\nu}(x)\,d\sigma(x)\;$ as

$$\phi(0)\left(\int_{\left\lvert x\right\rvert=R} K(x)\vec{\nu}(x)\,d\sigma(x)-\int_{\left\lvert x\right\rvert=\varepsilon} K(x)\vec{\nu}(x)\,d\sigma(x)\right) + \int_{\partial A(\varepsilon,R)}K(x)(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\vec{\nu}(x)\,d\sigma(x)$$

then two terms in the bracket w.r.t. $\phi(0)$ cancelled due to homogeneity, and the second term goes to $0$, when $\,\varepsilon\to 0,\,R\to\infty$, I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: The second term doesn't go to zero. Surface of the annulus is homogenous of degree n-1 which cancels homogeneity of K.

Comment: @Bananach what I mean is that the term inside the bracket w.r.t \phi(0) cancelled

Comment: sorry looked like three lines on my phone. I don't know what is going then. Only small note: I think you should remove the $\phi(x)$ in your second integral

Comment: @89085731: Is $\phi$ vector valued?

Comment: @levap just scalar

Comment: @89085731: Is $c$ a vector then? I'm slightly confused because the gradient $\nabla K$ is a vector so if you integrate it against a scalar you should get a vector but usually the gradient of a distribution acts on vector-valued test functions.

Comment: @levap I am actually here finding what is the distributional partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial j}$, writing in gradient form is just for simplicity

Comment: @levap u can just consider computing the distributional derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why the integral
$$
\int_{\partial A(\varepsilon,R)}K(x)(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\nu(x)\,d\sigma(x)
$$
goes to zero. Assume that $K(x)=\frac{x_{1}}{|x|^{n}}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \int_{|x|=\varepsilon}K(x)(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\nu(x)\,d\sigma
(x)\right\vert  & \leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{n-1}}\int_{|x|=\varepsilon}%
\Vert\nabla\phi\Vert_{\infty}|x|\,d\sigma(x)\\
& \leq\frac{\varepsilon\Vert\nabla\phi\Vert_{\infty}}{\varepsilon^{n-1}}%
\int_{|x|=\varepsilon}\,d\sigma(x)=\beta_{n}\varepsilon\Vert\nabla\phi
\Vert_{\infty}\to 0.
\end{align*}
If $\phi$ has compact support then for $R$ large and by homogeneity
\begin{align*}
\int_{|x|=R}K(x)(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\nu(x)\,d\sigma(x)  & =\int_{|x|=R}%
K(x)(0-\phi(0))\nu(x)\,d\sigma(x)\\
& =-\phi(0)\int_{|x|=R}K(x)\frac{x}{|x|}\,d\sigma(x)\\
& =-\phi(0)\int_{|x|=1}K(x)x\,d\sigma(x)\\
& =-\phi(0)\int_{|x|=1}x_{1}x\,d\sigma(x)
\end{align*}
and the last one is not zero in general.